# Problema al convertir objetos desde un select con Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Saludos, tengo una página en donde se deben hacer registros de un empleado en el que un atributo es un objeto (relación con otra tabla) y para especificarlo se hace mediante un select que en esta ocasión uso el de Spring pero obtengo el siguente error en la validación.

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required  type com.edw.model.Position for property position; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type 
com.edw.model.Position for property position: no matching editors or
conversion strategy found
```

Este error es mostrado en la vista cuando hace las validaciones, en la consola de tomcat no dice nada, esto es lo que tengo en la configuración de Spring para las conversiones.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <ref bean="positionFormatter" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Este es el conversor

```
@Component
public class PositionFormatter implements Formatter<Position> {
    @Autowired
    private PositionService positionService;

    @Override
    public String print(Position arg0, Locale arg1) {
        return arg0.getPositionName();
    }

    @Override
    public Position parse(String arg0, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
        try {
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(arg0);
            return positionService.getById(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

La clase `Empleado` tiene un atributo objeto que es la clase `Position` que a su vez contiene el atributo id

Este es el fragmento de código de la página jsp en donde se muestran mediante un select todos los cargos disponibles

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<label for="position">Cargo *</label>
<f:select path="position" class="form-control" id="position">
<f:option value="${null}" label="Seleccione..."></f:option>
<f:options items="${positions}" itemLabel="positionName" itemValue="id"/></f:select>
<f:errors path="position" cssClass="text-danger"></f:errors>
```

Este es el controlador:

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/guardar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid final Employee employee, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        try {
            List<Position> positions = positionService.getAll();
            model.addAttribute(positions);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "empleados/registro";
    }

    try {
        employeeService.create(employee);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@InitBinder
public void registerConversionServices(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    if(dataBinder.getConversionService() == null)
        dataBinder.setConversionService(conversionService);
}
```

Incluso quitando el `@Valid` sigue lanzando el error, gracias de antemano.

PD: Cuando muestra de nuevo la vista con los errores de validación lanzados, la lista de cargos en el `select` no se muestran.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de varias investigaciones e intentos he podido arreglar el problema, en primer lugar usé el convertidor de spring `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`:

```
public class PositionConverter implements Converter<String, Position> {

    @Autowired
    private PositionService positionService;

    @Override
    public Position convert(String id) {

        try {
            return positionService.getById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Y luego cambié el código para las conversiones de objetos en el archivo de configuración de spring:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.edw.converter.PositionConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Con esto, la conversión se efectúa y no fue necesario el método `registerConversionServices` que conlleva la anotación `@InitBinder` ni tampoco la instancia `ConversionService` que habia colocado antes del método

Comment: Me funciono lo que dijiste, pero el autowired en la clase positionservice no me funciona, en el controlador si